Expo: nvariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGRect" was not found in the UIManager
I am using expo for the first time for my mobile project. And everything is working great locally when I run expo run android for example, but if I build for production (apk) I get a weird error when I open some components in the app and the app will freeze
E  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGRect" was not found in the UIManager.
Why is this happening and how can I fix this? Thanks in advance
I tried removing all npm packages and reinstalling them, and some "debug steps" in android
